# Ubuntu 17.04 keeps freezing on asus x205ta

Tags: asus, freeze

As the title states my netbook keeps freezing on Ubuntu 17.04 keeps freezing on asus x205ta. I have looked at all the post about the freezing problems and what to do.

My problem is that nothing works at all. I can hit any combination of buttons and still nothing. I am not sure what to do or if it is just my netbook?

Specs for netbook:

```
Processor
Intel® Bay Trail-T Quad Core Z3735 1.33 GHz Processor
Operating System
Windows 10
Memory
DDR3L 1333 MHz SDRAM, 2 GB 
Display
11.6" 16:9 HD (1366x768) Glare panel
Graphic
Integrated Intel® HD Graphics
Storage
32GB eMMC
Card Reader
card reader (Micro SD Micro SDXC Micro SDHC )
Camera
VGA Web Camera
Networking
Built-in Bluetooth™ V4.0
Interface
1 x Microphone-in/Headphone-out jack 
2 x USB 2.0 port(s)
1 x micro HDMI

1 x micro SD card
Audio
Built-in Speakers And Microphone
SonicMaster
Battery
38 Whrs Polymer Battery
Power Adapter
Output :
19 V DC, 1.75 A, 33 W
Input :
100 -240 V AC, 50/60 Hz universal
Dimensions
286 x 193.3 x 17.5 mm (WxDxH)
Weight
2.16 lbs (with Polymer Battery)
Certificates
UL, MIC, CE Marking Compliance, FCC Compliance, BSMI, Australia C-TICK / NZ A-Tick Compliance, CCC, GOST-R, CB, Energy star, IDA, Erp 2013, RoHS, JATE
```

Comment: You could add the hardware specs to the question.

Comment: Added them good suggestion

Comment: The problem of freezes is [well known](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) with BayTrail systems. It is supposed to be resolved in kernel 4.11 and later, so you should install [Ubuntu 17.10](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/artful-desktop-amd64.iso), which is to be released on October 19th.

Comment: Okay I am super new to using ubuntu so is there a way to just upgrade? or do i have to do a complete new install, because I had to go through a lot of trouble to get the wifi working last time.

Comment: Yes, but what if it freezes during the upgrade? Also, the wifi solution wasn't too difficult, though it may have taken time to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: is it possible that the wifi may be fixed eventually in one of the upgrades or no?

Comment: Theoretically, it's not impossible, but I am not exactly sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: I have this device. It's the c-state bug, easily "fixed" as mentioned in the linked post

Comment: The link posted by @EliahKagan??

Comment: @Zanna the is the response from Eliah the one you are talking about?

Comment: Yes! That one. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeap, did everything you said on there and so far so good thank you :)